# Custom Annotations - defining @Target

Tags: java, intellij-idea, annotations, intellij-14

A bit new to defining custom annotations, what am I doing wrong:

from: [Target : Standard Annotations « Language « Java Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0020__Language/Target.htm)

> You can have multiple values in the Target annotation.
>
> @Target(value={TYPE, FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, CONSTRUCTOR,
>   LOCAL_VARIABLE})

However, I can't get this to work in my IDE

I must do something like this:

```
@Target(value={ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
```

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using `IntelliJ 14`

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: _cannot resolve Symbol **TYPE**_ and similar for the other values, when _ElementType._ is not present

Comment: You do have the correct imports ? (`java.lang.annotation.ElementType`)

Comment: yes, it gives the same error when that import is used, it was the first thing I tried - I'm using Java 8, don't know if that matters

Comment: Looks more like an Intellij issue than Java to me. Have you tried compiling outside Intellij ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add:

```
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
```

Comment: ah, that worked - thanks